# Error loading XSLT .....xslt , Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\.. + umbrco

Tags: asp.net, xslt, iis, umbraco, iis-8.5

web site in developed in Umbraco and use XSLT for searching website content.
Now I have changing Hosting server and start getting following . (Was working fine on old server and in local environment )

[image]

And following is the text format of the about attach image.

```
  Error loading XSLT search.xslt
    Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\w1hzfir2.0.cs' could not be found
      at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
      at umbraco.macro.CreateXsltTransform(XmlTextReader xslReader, Boolean debugMode)
      at umbraco.macro.getXslt(String XsltFile)
      at umbraco.macro.loadMacroXSLT(macro macro, Hashtable attributes, Hashtable pageElements)
```

is this is IIS access permission issue. ? or some thing else

hosting provider is using IIS 8.5
Site is point to net framework 4.0

Comment: You should really know better than posting code in an image. Please replace it with actual characters.

Comment: Its an Image of error Message. not code (As code is working fine ) And I am think it some permission issue. So I have attache error image to make it more clear.

Comment: I know, but error messages must be characters, too - not images. Images cannot be indexed and searched, for instance.

Comment: Ok added the text. error message.

Comment: Looks like permissions? Ensure the app pool identity has access to C:\Windows\Temp.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem with an old application after a server upgrade. Solved it by setting the TEMP environment variable. I simply added the following line to the Windows command line script that starts my EXE application:

```
SET TEMP=D:\TEMP
```